# Перемещение элементов в списке пример

Tags: python, list

Есть список
`a = [1, 2, 3]`.
Допустим мне нужно переместить 1 элемент на место 2, а 2 на 1:
`a = [2, 1, 3]`.Как это сделать?

Comment: Если вам все варианты надо, смотрите в сторону `permutations`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]
print(a)
```

> `[2, 1, 3]`